# Customize passenger-status output

Tags: passenger, ubuntu-12.04

We have a server running `Passenger 5.0.30` in a `Ubuntu 12.04` server and when we run `sudo passenger-status` we get very useful and concise information. To get more information there's an option `sudo passenger-status --show=requests` but that is just to much information to quickly identify problems with certain requests or even the server.

Is there any way to include in the `sudo passenger-status` output the current action that each process is working? If not, any thoughts or recommendations on how to create maybe a command that parses this information and outputs what I need?

Example of the `sudo passenger-status` output:

```
Version : 5.0.30                      1
Date    : 2015-07-06 12:18:38 +0200   2
Instance: bdVuBLEf (nginx/1.8.0 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.13)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 9                 3
App groups    : 2                 4
Processes     : 3
Requests in top-level queue : 0   5

----------- Application groups -----------
/var/www/phusion_blog/current/public:
  App root: /var/www/phusion_blog/current
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 18334   Sessions: 0       Processed: 4595    Uptime: 5h 53m 29s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 99M     Last used: 4s ago
  * PID: 18339   Sessions: 0       Processed: 2873    Uptime: 5h 53m 26s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 29s ago
```

Example of the `sudo passenger-status --show=requests` output (I would be specially interested in the `path` attribute):

```
{
   "threads" : 2,
   "thread1" : {
      "active_client_count" : 1,
      "active_clients" : {
         "2-2315" : {
            "connected_at" : {
               "local" : "Mon Jul  6 13:19:13 2015",
               "relative" : "0s ago",
               "timestamp" : 1436181553.120679
            },
            "connection_state" : "ACTIVE",
            "current_request" : {
               "app_response_http_state" : "PARSING_HEADERS",
               "app_sink_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : false
               },
               "app_source_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : true
               },
               "flags" : {
                  "dechunk_response" : true,
                  "https" : true,
                  "request_body_buffering" : false
               },
               "host" : "blog.phusion.nl",
               "http_major" : 1,
               "http_minor" : 1,
               "http_state" : "COMPLETE",
               "method" : "GET",
               "path" : "/",
               "refcount" : 1,
               "request_body_already_read" : 0,
               "request_body_fully_read" : true,
               "request_body_type" : "NO_BODY",
               "response_begun" : false,
               "session" : {
                  "gupid" : "16d1dbc-9VEXQm82is",
                  "pid" : 18334
               },
               "session_checkout_try" : 1,
               "started_at" : {
                  "local" : "Mon Jul  6 13:19:13 2015",
                  "relative" : "0s ago",
                  "timestamp" : 1436181553.121373
               },
               "state" : "WAITING_FOR_APP_OUTPUT",
               "sticky_session" : false,
               "want_keep_alive" : false
            },
            "lingering_request_count" : 0,
            "name" : "2-2315",
            "number" : 2315,
            "output_channel_state" : {
               "bytes_buffered" : {
                  "bytes" : 0,
                  "human_readable" : "0 bytes"
               },
               "callback_in_progress" : false,
               "mode" : "IN_MEMORY_MODE",
               "nbuffers" : 0,
               "reader_state" : "RS_INACTIVE"
            },
            "refcount" : 2,
            "requests_begun" : 1
         }
      },
      "disconnected_client_count" : 0,
      "disconnected_clients" : {},
      "free_client_count" : 127,
      "free_request_count" : 3,
      "mbuf_pool" : {
         "active_blocks" : 4,
         "active_memory" : {
            "bytes" : 2048,
            "human_readable" : "2.0 KB"
         },
         "chunk_size" : 512,
         "free_blocks" : 10,
         "offset" : 448,
         "spare_memory" : {
            "bytes" : 5120,
            "human_readable" : "5.0 KB"
         }
      },
      "pid" : 5171,
      "server_state" : "ACTIVE",
      "total_bytes_consumed" : 9209549,
      "total_clients_accepted" : 2315,
      "total_requests_begun" : 2315,
      "turbocaching" : {
         "fetches" : 1,
         "hit_ratio" : 0.0,
         "hits" : 0,
         "store_success_ratio" : null,
         "store_successes" : 0,
         "stores" : 1
      }
   },
   "thread2": {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Write a script. That's well-formed JSON data so it's easy to parse. Long answer involves a demonstration of **what you tried**.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not shure how to approach this, I have little experience with scrpting in Linux / Ubuntu. Would this be a bash script (*.sh)? I'm trying to get orientation on where to start

Comment: Whatever you're most comfortable with. Python? Ruby? Perl? Node.js? Pick one and run with it. Since you haven't defined what a better output might be, this question is too broad, but it should be solvable if you can find the right tools. Use a scripting language to run the status command, parse the JSON, and then wrangle it into whatever new format you desire.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable in python (or even if you aren't), you can do the following :

```
import os
import json
import types

stream = os.popen("/path/to/passenger/directory/passenger-status --show=requests")
output = stream.read()
index_of_json_string_opening = output.find("{")
string_json = output[index_of_json_string_opening:]
requests_data = json.loads(string_json)

# for all threads
for thread in requests_data.keys():
  if isinstance(requests_data[thread], dict):
    # if there are active clients,
    if requests_data[thread]['active_client_count'] > 0:
      for active_client in requests_data[thread]['active_clients']:
        # get the data about the individual active clients & retrieve the current_request data
        current_request = requests_data[thread]['active_clients'][active_client]['current_request']

        # retrieve the path
        path = current_request['path']

        started_at = current_request['started_at']['local']

        # check if the session exists, i.e. if any thread is currently processing this, then the PID shall exist
        if 'session' in current_request:
          pid = current_request['session']['pid']
        else:
          pid = "NOT FOUND"

        print("PATH : " + str(path))
        print("PID : " + str(pid))
        print("Started at : " + str(started_at))
        print("\n")
```

The output shall be in the following manner:

```
PATH : /some/path/here
PID : 50415
Started at : Thu Apr 23 15:19:34 2020


PATH : /some/path/here
PID : 50422
Started at : Thu Apr 23 15:19:34 2020


PATH : /some/path/here
PID : NOT FOUND
Started at : Thu Apr 23 15:19:34 2020
```

Similarly, you can retrieve other important parameters of the request/thread as well.

Refer https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/standalone/overall_status_report.html for more understanding of the `--show=requests` output.